# Access gmail star color from IMAP

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

Gmail has more stars than just the yellow colored star but they are not enabled by default.
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=5904

Is it possible to search for all messages in Gmail with a certain star color from an IMAP client?

I have tried the following with no success:

```
tag SEARCH X-GM-RAW "has:red-star"

tag SEARCH X-GM-RAW "has:red-star in:inbox"

tag SEARCH X-GM-RAW "has:red-star in:anywhere"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that should totally work. From the [Gmail IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw) page:

> **Extension of the SEARCH command: X-GM-RAW**
>
> To provide access to the full Gmail search syntax, Gmail provides the
>   X-GM-RAW search attribute. Arguments passed along with the X-GM-RAW
>   attribute when executing the SEARCH or UID SEARCH commands will be
>   interpreted in the same manner as in the Gmail web interface.

For stars, the [advanced search syntax for Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) notes that you can use these query parameters:

```
has:yellow-star
has:red-star
has:orange-star
has:green-star
has:blue-star
has:purple-star
has:red-bang
has:orange-guillemet
has:yellow-bang
has:green-check
has:blue-info
has:purple-question
```

Does your search work without `has:red-star`?