# Working with GMail Stars in ActiveUp MailSystem

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

I'm using [ActiveUp MailSystem](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) for an automated mail retrieve and treatment program in C# at work.

In the GMail browser mail cliente, my colleagues use GMail stars to mark a specific mail as handled or to be handled by nother colleague (they all use the same account, but some take care of some subjects while others take care of other subjects, and starring gives them a visual aid into what's taken care off and what's addressed to them by a colleague.

Using the `inbox.Fetch.MessageObjectPeekWithGMailExtensions(uid)` i can get which messages are starred by looking at `msg.HeaderFields["x-gm-labels"]` and checking it contains `\Starred`, however:

1 - How can i find out which start it is set to?
2 - how can i set/change a star on a particular message?

Any help is fully appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Starred label only indicates that the mail can be found on the Starred mailbox. Gmail uses different IMAP mailboxes for labels. MailSystem isn't fully compatible with Gmail's enhanced IMAP commands yet (doesn't support mail's threadID for example).
You can check if IMAP actually stores the *type* of star by issuing a *command* method to the IMAP4Client class, that brings the full message (through the BODY IMAP command), but unfortunately you will have to parse and figure out the meaning of each parameter.
Other solution as Max said is using the X-GM-RAW enhanced search command to check for mails starred with the desired star, in which case you will have to use Gmail's unique identifier to know which email has which star.

Comment: Which doesn't give me the star of na email but the emails with a star. But it's starting to look like my only option. Also MailSystem CAN get the threadid - not sure if getmessageobjectwithgmailextensions gets it (can't recall) but you can use X-GM-THRID for it

Comment: Accepted by lack of better options

Answer (score 0):

Google maps stars to imap \Flagged flag, so you can just manipulate and look for that. Eg, store flag \Flagged, and the message will become starred.

Comment: That neiter gives me which star nor allows me to choose a star to put in the message - which i explicitly asked for. Alos in ActiveUp MailSystem at least - which i also explicitly said i was using, i'm getting flag null with starred messages

Comment: I don't believe which star is exposed via IMAP.  I believe it only knows if a message is starred (maybe with the default star?)

Comment: Maybe you should use labels, which you manipulate with x-gm-labels, and see `https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions` for the extensions that are available.

Comment: i AM looking at x-gm-labels - but as i said, it only comes back with \Starred - i have read somewhere about x-gm-raw beeing the way to check/set which star but found no examples

Comment: Like I said, I don't think this is exported via IMAP.  Use *actual* labels rather than stars.

Comment: using stars is a requirement as it needs to match the gmail browser mail client for when they look it up from home - if it wasn't for that i'd easily build my own system using a local database which would have been easier and i have already done - but they don't use it because it doesn't propagate to the browser client

Comment: Then you are screwed, as it appears this information plain isn't available through Google IMAP gateway.

Comment: X-GM-Raw allows you to search using their query language. Can you, using the browser, come up with a search query for each star you're interested in?

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184225/access-gmail-star-color-from-imap -> has:red-star, has:yellow-star, etc - only those get all messages with specified star - not the stars of a specific message - also no mention on how to set a star - although i read elsewhere it's using the same sintax as folders

Comment: Thunderbird used to have na add-on that allowed users to do just what i am looking for - so this IS exposed through gmail IMAP extensions - i just can't seem to find any accurate information on how

Comment: reading my own comments above makes me realize i am so close but missing something tremendasly obvious